# Format Array into new Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have an array of objects.  I would like to reformat into a new array but am not sure how to begin.  I have jQuery and Underscore available.

Here is my original array:

```
var myArray = [
  {
    "name": "Product",
    "value": "Car"
  },
  {
    "name": "Product",
    "value": "Boat"
  },
  {
    "name": "Product",
    "value": "Truck"
  },
  {
    "name": "Color",
    "value": "Blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "Location",
    "value": "Store"
  }
];
```

Here is what I am trying to make the new Array look like:

```
var newArray = [
  {
    "name": "Product",
    "value": "Car Boat Truck"
  },
  {
    "name": "Color",
    "value": "Blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "Location",
    "value": "Store"
  }
];
```

In the newArray the Products are all in one object.

Comment: Nice, I have a working solution here. I just want it improved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945735/condensing-a-collection-of-objects-using-underscore-js. Just take my solution and instead of using an array, convert the array to a string and you'll have what you want.

Comment: Well, have you started coding it?

Comment: two people basically asking for the same less-than-generic thing inside of an hour.. homework?

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819116/how-to-group-a-collection-of-data-by-its-keys-using-underscore-js/22924056#22924056

Comment: @aldux, I have here is a fiddle of where I'm at http://jsfiddle.net/pWtL3/

Comment: @CrayonViolent Nah, not homework. I'm looking at optimizing this use case for work as it's a useful function to summarize groups of objects and build table summaries out of them...

Comment: @CrayonViolent Not homework.  Just learning underscore methods and a friend is trying to format an array of objects similiar to the above.  That is interesting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) method to get all the elements with the same name together, then [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to transform them into what you want. And [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) is useful here to combine the values in the output array.

Here's quick, simple solution:

```
var newArray = _.chain(myArray)
                .groupBy("name")
                .map(function(a) { 
                    return { 
                        "name": a[0].name, 
                        "value":  _.pluck(a, "value").join(" ")
                    };
                })
                .value();
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/u28Vw/)

And just for completeness, here's the non-chained version:

```
var newArray = _.map(_.groupBy(myArray, "name"), function(a) { 
                    return { 
                        "name": a[0].name, 
                        "value":  _.pluck(a, "value").join(" ")
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought that this is the kind of thing Underscore would be great at but have just started trying to learn it.  I had not even seen the .chain() method yet.

Comment: @Mdd Glad I could help. [`chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) is basically just a way to compose underscore methods more gracefully. See my updated answer for an equivalent non-chained solution. That may help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more generalized solution that's reusable and not hard-coded. This way, you can create multiple groupBy methods for different properties of different object collections, then join the properties that you require. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pWtL3/7/)

```
function groupBy(groupBy) {    
    return function(source, joinOn) {
        return _.each(_.groupBy(source, groupBy), function(val, key, context){
            context[key] = _.pluck(val, joinOn).join(' ');
        });
    };
}

var groupByNameOn = groupBy('name');
console.log(groupByNameOn(arr, 'value'));
```

Comment: That's really awesome!  It's kind of funny that we were looking into the same sort of situation. :)